# How to change the color of cell in javafx tableview?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want all the cell to be white. So I use...

```
.list-cell:selected {
   -fx-background-color: #fff;
}
```

...in the CSS, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: sorry i writed wrongly  . no  selected.

Comment: sorry my English is poor...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make it clear what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this question:

[Styling a TableView in CSS (JavaFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938811/styling-a-tableview-in-css-javafx)

Also... .list-cell has nothing to do with tables. Where did you get the idea to use **that**?